# Does Cordova support iPod Touch and Indoor Positioning System

Tags: ios, cordova, ipod-touch

I have requirement to support iPod Touch as a part of cross platform cordova application. Application should use Indoor Positioning System using wifi triangulation or any other approach to locate and map objects.

Does cordova support iPod Touch, if So what are the Pros and Cons, Challenges while implementing solution?
Does iPod touch can be used for Indoor Positioning System and How to achieve it using cordova like using wifi triangulation or any other third party sdks(please suggest)?
Can ipod Touch camera can be used to capture and process images like to read QR code etc. Please suggest any third party api's
Thanks,
Phani

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with iPod touches, but in theory there should be no problem with using them for indoor positioning.

Wifi triangulation is not possible to do with iOS devices (you are only able to obtain the info about the Wifi base station you are attached to), and thus not the optimal solution. I would do this with Bluetooth beacons, which the iPod touch should be able to support well. With beacons you can do triangulation and get to approximately 2m accuracy. The easiest way to get that functioning is through a Cordova plugin. I work for a company called Proximi.io that is a unified positioning platform. All you have to do is place your beacons in their correct positions on our portal, and our libraries will handle the rest. We also have a Cordova plugin.

That being said, we haven't tested our SDKs with iPod touches, so I would recommend testing it first. I also think that the camera usage should be possible, but unfortunately cannot help you more with that.